# How can i upload captured image on Facebook in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

i am saving the captured image in document folder how can i upload this image on Facebook.can anybody give me the link or demo code to upload image on fb in iPhone sdk

Comment: You need to check out FB SDK documentation on developer.facebook.com.
You will get each and every detail on it.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ should get you started.